# How can I reload a page in php after I submit a form (method=post)

Tags: php

I have a php page that contains a form with information I post to another php page.

When I click submit, it opens a new page in a target="_blank" and posts form data.  However, after that happens, I want to reload the current page.  Is this possible?  I would also settle for redirecting the existing page to another, if reloading is not possible.

Is this achievable?

Comment: Why open a new page if you're going to just reload the current page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
<form action="..." target="_blank" 
  onsubmit="setTimeout('location.reload()', 500);">
...
</form>
```

Or for redirecting:

```
<form action="..." target="_blank" 
  onsubmit="setTimeout('location.href=\'/new/url\'', 500);">
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set a hidden form field with the URL of the page you want the user redirected to. Then after the form is processed use `header()` to redirect the user to that page. You can also use a session for this.